# Using virtual environments on a drive restricted for execution by group policy

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtual, environment, group-policy

My documents are stored on a network drive restricted by a group policy to prevent from running `.exe` from it. When I create a virtual environment it copies `python.exe` in the directory and executes it from there instead of from `Program Files`.

Is there a way to use virtual environments, by to execute `python.exe` from the `Program Files` folder? I tried with the `--symlinks` and the `--system-site-packages` switches but that doesn't seem to do the job I need.

Exact message I get when creating the `venv`:

```
python -m venv env

Error: [WinError 1260] This program is blocked by group policy. 
       For more information, contact your system administrator
```